# How to do boolean exclusive or?

Tags: f#

Apparently there is no boolean version of the bitwise exclusive-or operator `(^^^)`... what to do?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is provided by the not-equal operator `<>`.

Comment: Okay. I'm stumped. How is `<>` a replacement for boolean xor?

Comment: `<>` is True when the inputs are different, and False when the inputs are the same. This is exactly what the xor operation does.

Comment: Of course! I asked that too hastily. Makes you wonder why C# has it. In F#, one slight difference an xor operator would make is inferring its operands to be of type bool.

Comment: Doy, yes this works, thanks. But I see using `<>` results in the F# compiler emitting something like `call x; call y; ceq; ldc.i4.0; ceq` while the C# compiler will emit `call x; call y; xor` for `^`... I wonder if there are (micro) performance implications there.

Comment: It is possible to emit the `xor` instruction using inline IL, but this feature is deprecated and they've told us they intend on removing it in the next version: `let inline xor (x:bool) (y:bool) = (# "xor" x y : bool #)`

Answer (score 4):

```
let inline xor a b = (a || b) && not (a && b)
```

Comment: Why inline if the type is known to be bool?  Also why not `let xor a b = if a then not b else b` or even `let xor a b = a <> b`?