# Operators precedence and association

Tags: f#, operators

I defined a XOR operator:

```
let (.||.) x y = (x || y) && not(x && y)
```

Such that

```
true .||. true
true .||. false
```

do return `false` and `true` respectively.

According to [Hansen & Rischel](https://www.amazon.it/Functional-Programming-Using-Michael-Hansen/dp/1107684064/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1486402238&sr=8-1&keywords=hansen+functional), the `&&` operator has higher precedence over the `||` operator (and the `.||.` operator too. Hence, why

```
    true .||. true && false
    true .||. false && true
```

do return `false` and `true` respectively? The results appears to be produced by
`(true .||. true) && false` instead of the expected `true .||. (true && false)`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656054/how-to-do-boolean-exclusive-or (for [IMO] better alternative `<>` and performance considerations).

Comment: That crosswiring of logic gates somehow grates the eye. Why not `let (^^) = function true -> not | _ -> id`, even if it doesn't help with precedence?

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/index), the operator `.||.` would fall under the pattern `|op` (i.e. ignoring leading dot, starting with pipe), which is two lines below operator `&&` in the table, on the same line with `&op` and `<op` among others. So it actually has *higher* precedence than `&&`.

The [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) says the same thing in section 4.4.2, only the table is upside down there (highest to lowest).

Can't comment on the book you're reading, don't have it handy.

Comment: Thanks the answer. Just for the sport, I quote "The system determines the precedence and association of declared operators on the basis of the characters of the operators. In the case of .||. the periods have no influence on this, so the precedence and association of .||. will be the same of || .", p. 35. Should I consider it an error?

Comment: No, it's absolutely correct: the precedence of `.||.` is the same as `||.`. The book gives you correct information. What is incorrect is your assumption that the precedence of `||.` is the same as the precedence of `||`, and therefore lower than the precedence of `&&`.

Comment: Got it. I naively misinterpreted the punctuation. Thank you for your patience.